# Update an item and trigger change (whether disabled or not)

Tags: javascript, jquery

In multiple parts of my code I need to update the value of an item, and in some cases it may have been disabled for user input; but in all cases I want the "change" event to fire, regardless.

I need a function that will take a jQuery expression, and a new value to set any corresponding item(s) to the new value; and then fire the "change" event on them. If the item was disabled, it should remain disabled.

jQuery 1.7.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest you to make the `<input>` readonly instead of disabled.

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/r39j48k2/10/)

```js
$("#form").on("change", ".all", function() {
  $("#feedback").append($(this).attr("id") + " changed<br>");
});

$(".all")
  .val("new value")
  .trigger("change");
```

```css
input[readonly] {
  background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="form">
  Item1 =
  <input id="item1" class="all">
  <br>Item2 =
  <input id="item2" class="all" readonly />
  <!--                          ^^^^^^^^ -->
  <p id="feedback">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what I have at the moment; it seems inelegant to me, hoping to see if there's a better way to do it:

```
function updVal (qry, nwVal) {

  $(qry+":not([disabled])")
    .val(nwVal)
    .trigger("change");

  // we need to temporarily enable then disable the disabled items
  // in order for the change event to fire
  $(qry+":disabled")
    .val(nwVal)
    .prop("disabled",false)
    .trigger("change")
    .prop("disabled",true);

}
```

e.g.

```
updVal("#myreport input[data-x='bla']", "new value");
```

Comment: If you want to invoke `change` handler, you can just call `handler` function with the `.call(ELEMENT)` to have `this-context` as `element`

Comment: @RayonDabre, could I impose on you to elaborate on that in a separate answer?

Comment: @RayonDabre, I tried `$(qry).val(nwVal).change.call(this);` but it complains that "Uncaught TypeError: this.trigger is not a function" - what am I getting wrong?